# (Android) Enable button only when all login fields are not giving an error

Tags: android, validation, authentication

been looking for a previous answer for this but can't seem to find an android version of it...

I'm making a login page for an app, and I've got 3 input fields (First name, last name, email) and a text watcher to tell the user if there's an error in their input ((e.g. nothing there/too long/not a valid email). I'm trying to make the log in button disabled until no errors are showing, but I can't seem to sort it. I'm very new to android, just been working from scraps of tutorials here and there really... I've tried setting a boolean for each input value that sets to false when the input is bad/true when it's acceptable, and something to check if all 3 are true or not to enable/disable the button but that doesn't seem to work...

In the emulator, the button doesn't disable at all and I've got warnings that the booleans I made are always true even though I've given instances to make them false, and defined them as false at the start...

Here's my java class at the moment:

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher {
    EditText firstName;
    EditText lastName;
    EditText eMail;
    ImageButton Begin;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initialiseUI();
    }

    private void initialiseUI() {

        eMail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
        eMail.addTextChangedListener(this);

        firstName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_firstname);
        firstName.addTextChangedListener(this);

        lastName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_surname);
        lastName.addTextChangedListener(this);

        Begin= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Beginbutton);
        Begin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    boolean name=false;
    boolean surname=false;
    boolean email=false;

    boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence eMail) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(eMail)
                .matches();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Is_Valid_Email(eMail);
        Is_Valid_Name(firstName);
        Is_Valid_Surname(lastName);
        Is_Login_Valid();
    }

    public void Is_Valid_Name(EditText firstName) {
        if (firstName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            firstName.setError("Enter Name");
            name=false;}
        else if (firstName.getText().toString().length()>20){
            firstName.setError("Name too long!");
            name=false;}
        else if (firstName.getText().toString().length()>1){
            firstName.setError(null);
            name=true;}
    }

    public void Is_Valid_Surname(EditText lastName){
        if (lastName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            lastName.setError("Enter Surname");
            surname=false;}
        else if (lastName.getText().toString().length()>20){
            lastName.setError("Surname too long!");
            surname=false;}
        else if (lastName.getText().toString().length()>1){
            lastName.setError(null);
            surname=true;}
    }

    public void Is_Valid_Email(EditText eMail) {
        if (eMail.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            eMail.setError("Enter e-mail");
            email=false;}
        else if (!isEmailValid(eMail.getText().toString())) {
            eMail.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            email=false;}
        else if (isEmailValid(eMail.getText().toString())) {
            email=true;}
        }

    public void Is_Login_Valid() {
        if (name=true){
            if (surname=true){
                if (email=true){
                    Begin.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if (email=false){
                    Begin.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            else if(surname=false){
                Begin.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        else if (name=false){
            Begin.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Login button */
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, question_1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the name, surname, email booleans & Is_Login_Valid terms entirely and copied the acceptable conditions from Is_Valid_Name, Is_Valid_Surname and Is_Valid_Email into an if statement within the button's onClick term as below, and it seems to work fine now:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if   ((firstName.getText().toString().length() >= 1) 
           && (firstName.getText().toString().length() < 20) 
           && (lastName.getText().toString().length() >= 1) 
           && (lastName.getText().toString().length() < 20) 
           && (isEmailValid(eMail.getText().toString())))
           {Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, question_1.class);
            startActivity(intent);}
        else{ //TODO Login failed animation or popup
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check setClickable(false)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29

Comment: Thanks, setClickable worked much better for disabling the button than setEnabled, although I was still having trouble making it re-enable with the validation. I've ended up avoiding disabling it altogether & just making the button not progress to the next activity if the validation fails which seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use variables for check status. Have you tried what happens when a screen rotation? This might be chaos.

I recommend you to check your status everytime the text changes:

```
 public void Is_Login_Valid() {
        if(Is_Valid_Name(firstName) && Is_Valid_Surname(lastName) && Is_Valid_Email(eMail)){
           Begin.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
           Begin.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but apparently it wouldn't let me re-use the Is_Valid_X() terms in that because they're void rather than boolean (converting to that didn't help either), and refused to let me use && in that if statement for some reason too. I've ended up having to reuse the terms for valid email/name/surname from within those in an if statement on the button itself and seem to have it working that way instead now.